# Extract substrings from the Snippet string in Ultisnips

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

So I have been working with vim-tex and ultisnips lately.
Let us say the snippet is of the form `(\d)pder`. It is a 5 character snippet and the first character can be accessed by `match.group(1)`.

But now I want to access substrings of the snippet with unspecified number of characters using certain pattern. For example, if `pderxaybzc` I want to extract the substring `xaybzc` by removing `pder`, so that each character of the output substring can be used within the snippet definition in different places.
I have tried looking for solutions and haven't found any.

Is this feature present in Ultisnips and can the above mentioned be done?

(Thank you in advance)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I wonder if extending the snippet like `(\d)pder(\w*)` would work?

Comment: It perfectly works! Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to self-answer :) answers belong in Answers, not comments, but you know better than I what worked

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet worked out for me:

```
snippet `pder(\w*)` "Description" rw
\\frac{\\partial^{`!p snip.rv=findSum(match.group(1))`}}{`!p snip.rv=printd("\\partial",match.group(1))`} $0
endsnippet
```

with

```
global !p
def findSum(str1): 
    # A temporary str1ing 
    temp = 0
  
    # holds sum of all numbers 
    # present in the str1ing 
    Sum = 0
    icount=0
    # read each character in input string 
    for ch in str1: 
  
        # if current character is a digit 
        if (ch.isdigit()): 
            Sum += int(ch) 
            icount=icount+1
    Sum=Sum+len(str1)-2*icount
    # atoi(temp.c_str1()) takes care 
    # of trailing numbers 
    return Sum

endglobal
```

I should at that `*` here would mean that, in the group `()` it would check for the zero,single or multiple instance of the previous occurring character. So here it checks for multiple alphanumeric, which is just a string.

Also one can use `+` in place of `*` if they want at least one character to be present for the expansion of snippet. Like `(\w+)` would require the snippet to have at least one character to expand.

Edit: The limitation of the code is that the derivative can have only natural number powers of 1 digit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend the snippet to `(\d)pder(\w*)` and handle the second submatch appropriately.